# Hunting down ModelState.IsValid errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

Is there a good way in asp.net MVC to trace ModelState errors? IsValid returns false when I submit my form even if there aren't actually any fields in it, or anything being validated. I looked at [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684445/what-can-cause-viewdata-modelstate-isvalid-to-become-false) and tried Steve Willcock's suggestion but no exceptions are thrown, just a generic error.

Is there any way I can see what is causing the ModelState to become invalid without stepping through every single part of the model that's used? It's quite large and I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue and found that in my model I had a unique id of type int that was causing a problem.  When I set it to nullable in my model the error went away.

W/out seeing any of your code though it's a bit hard to figure out but the above helped me.

I also noticed that when I was doing validations, using the Nerd Dinner approach, I would sometimes get an error popup saying something like "Value Required".  Linked it to the same problem and made all Id's nullable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to track down the error and it was in fact exactly what you describe. Get's fairly hard to debug when you have very large entities. I wish there was a more detailed error or exception thrown when this happens.