# Why ModelState.IsValid always return false in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my controller this code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Company company, FormCollection IsCostCenters)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Company objNewCompany = new Company();
                //oParty.CostCenters.Clear();

                using (PaymentAdviceEntityContainer db1 = new PaymentAdviceEntityContainer())
                {
                    objNewCompany = db1.Companies.Find(company.Id);

                    objNewCompany.CostCenters.Clear();

                    string[] temp = IsCostCenters["CostCenters"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    foreach (var s in temp)
                    {
                        if (s != "false")
                        {

                            CostCenter oCostCenter = new CostCenter();
                            oCostCenter = db1.CostCenters.Find(Convert.ToInt32(s));
                            objNewCompany.CostCenters.Add(oCostCenter);
                        }
                    }
                    db1.SaveChanges();
                }

                db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.CreatedById = new SelectList(db.Employees, "Id", "FirstName", company.CreatedById);
            return View(company);
        }
```

And my view  code as below

```
@using PaymentAdviceEntity;
@{

    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    List<CostCenter> clist = new List<CostCenter>();
    clist = ((List<CostCenter>)ViewBag.CostCenters).ToList();
}



                       <div style="line-height: 22px; width: 100%;height :3%; float: left; ">
                       @{
    foreach (var item in clist)
    {                      
                             <div  style="line-height: 22px; width: 28%; float: left;">
                                                <span class="checkbox">@Html.CheckBox("CostCenters", item.IsChecked, new { @value = item.Id })</span>
                                               <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</span>

                              </div> 

    }
}
```

So please what is reason `ModelState.IsValid` is return false in page post time ...

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684445/what-can-cause-viewdata-modelstate-isvalid-to-become-false)

Comment: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'PaymentAdviceEntity.CostCenter' failed because no type converter can convert between these types.===>
Above Error  occurs how to solve this  error please tell me

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Please post your *Model* Class.

To check the errors in your `ModelState` use the following code:

```
var errors = ModelState
    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors })
    .ToArray();
```

**OR:** You can also use

```
var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
```

Place a break point at the above line and see what are the errors in your `ModelState`.

Comment: post the error message

Comment: The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'PaymentAdviceEntity.CostCenter' failed because no type converter can convert between these types

Comment: this error message occured

Comment: where are you getting that error message

Comment: in create controller => ModelState.isValid that part i checked that part i find error

Comment: +1. I was able to debug my app thanks to your answer.

Comment: This is now my first (and permanent) Watch: ModelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value.Errors }).ToArray();

Comment: Why would you provide two ways of doing something when one is 4 lines and more complex, and the other one which does the same thing is smaller and only one line?

Answer (score 13):

As Brad Wilson states in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881351/19679):

> ModelState.IsValid tells you if any model errors have been added to
>   ModelState.
>
> The default model binder will add some errors for basic type
>   conversion issues (for example, passing a non-number for something
>   which is an "int"). You can populate ModelState more fully based on
>   whatever validation system you're using.

Try using :-

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var errors = ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors.Select(z => z.Exception));

    // Breakpoint, Log or examine the list with Exceptions.
}
```

If it helps catching you the error. [Courtesy this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791570/modelstate-isvalid-false-why) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684445/what-can-cause-viewdata-modelstate-isvalid-to-become-false)

Comment: When you copy the words of others, you must be explicit in quoting and attributing that wording. I've edited this answer to do this, but you must do this yourself in the future.

Comment: @BradLarson , First of all apologies for missing the courtesy part. I have tried putting courtesy part always ; like i have given at the end. This is my mistake if i have missed the link to Brad Wilson's answer. Apologies!

Answer (score 4):

"ModelState.IsValid" tells you that the model is consumed by the view (i.e. PaymentAdviceEntity) is satisfy all types of validation or not specified in the model properties by DataAnotation.

In this code the view does not bind any model properties.
So if you put any DataAnotations or validation in model (i.e. PaymentAdviceEntity). then the validations are not satisfy.
say if any properties in model is Name which makes required in model.Then the value of the property remains blank after post.So the model is not valid (i.e. ModelState.IsValid returns false).
You need to remove the model level validations.